# Search word in html and show specific content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I am trying to build search filter with jQuery. First I am hiding every content of html using `$(list).find('p').hide();`.

What I am trying to do is when a user enter text into text box, it should find that word in html and if found it should show whole content with in its`<div>`. I don't know what I am doing wrong?
here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xgd9ht0/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script> 

(function ($) {
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
    };
    function listFilter(header, list) {
        $(list).find('p').hide();
        var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
            input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text"}),
            search = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterbutton","type":"button","name":"btn1","value":"Search"});
        $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);

        $(input)
            .change( function () {
                var filter = $(this).val();
                if(filter) {
                    $(list).find("p:contains("+filter+")").closest("div").show();
                } else {
                    $(list).find('p').hide();
                }
                return false;
            })
            .keyup( function () {
                $(this).change();
            });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
    });
}(jQuery));
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="header">Collection</h1>
<div id="list">

<div id='p1'>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
</div>

<div id='p2'>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
</div>

<div id='p3'>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
<p>addin</p>
</div>

<div id='p4'>
<p>Forth Paragraph</p>
<p>Begins</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently I want to achieve this using button click instead of text change event. I am trying to create button on the fly

```
search = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterbutton","type":"button","name":"btn1","value":"Search"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xgd9ht0/2/)**.

You was so close, all you need is to made two small changes :

1. You need to use the expression `:Contains` that you just create at the start of your script, so `p:contains` should be `p:Contains` in :

   ```
   $(list).find("p:Contains("+filter+")")
   ```
2. You should show the paragraph `p` when it match and not the parent div, so just replace :

   ```
   selector.closest("div").show();
   ```

   By :

   ```
   selector.show();
   ```

The full line that the problem comes from should be :

```
$(list).find("p:Contains("+filter+")").show();
```

Hope this helps.

---

**NOTE :** I suggest to always hide the paragraphs before performing the match and then no need for the `else` clause, and I suggest also the use of `input` instead of `change/keyup` events.

```js
(function ($) {
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
  };
  
  function listFilter(header, list) {
    $(list).find('p').hide();
    var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
        input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text"}),
        search = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterbutton","type":"button","name":"btn1","value":"Search"});
        
    $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);

    $(input).on('input', function () {
      var filter = $(this).val();
      
      $(list).find('p').hide();
      
      if(filter) {
        $(list).find("p:Contains("+filter+")").show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="header">Collection</h1>

<div id="list">
  <div id='p1'>
    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p2'>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p3'>
    <p>Third Paragraph</p>
    <p>addin</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p4'>
    <p>Forth Paragraph</p>
    <p>Begins</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like you found the problem and your suggestion to always hide the paragraphs before performing the match also helped.